# def next() for Python pre-2.6? (instead of object.next method)

Tags: python, python-2.5

Python 2.6+ and 3.* have next(), but pre-2.6 only offers the object.next method.  Is there a way to get the next() style in pre-2.6; some "def next():" construction perhaps?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
class Throw(object): pass
throw = Throw() # easy sentinel hack
def next(iterator, default=throw):
  """next(iterator[, default])

  Return the next item from the iterator. If default is given
  and the iterator is exhausted, it is returned instead of
  raising StopIteration.
  """
  try:
    iternext = iterator.next.__call__
    # this way an AttributeError while executing next() isn't hidden
    # (2.6 does this too)
  except AttributeError:
    raise TypeError("%s object is not an iterator" % type(iterator).__name__)
  try:
    return iternext()
  except StopIteration:
    if default is throw:
      raise
    return default
```

(`throw = object()` works too, but this generates better docs when inspecting, e.g. `help(next)`. `None` is not suitable, because you must treat `next(it)` and `next(it, None)` differently.)

Comment: @pantsgolem pointed out that in Python 3, `next()` raises `TypeError` when you call it on a non-iterator.  I edited this answer to catch `AttributeError` and re-raise it as `TypeError`.  (I hope this is good StackOverflow etiquette; this is the first time I have edited someone else's answer!)

Comment: More importantly, next() in 2.6 raises TypeError in that case. Editing to include it is fine by me, though I modified the raise.

Answer (score 6):

R. Pate seems to have a good answer.  One extra bell to add: if you're writing code to run on many different versions of Python, you can conditionalize the definition:

```
try:
    next = next
except NameError:
    def next():
        # blah blah etc
```

That way you have `next` defined in any case, but you're using the built in implementation where it's available.

I use `next = next` so that I can put this definition in a module, then elsewhere in my code use:

```
from backward import next
```

Comment: Can't the test just be next? E.g. `try: next; except ...`

Comment: It has to do with the way I include these definitions in my project.  I've udpated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Simpler method:

```
import operator

next = operator.methodcaller("next")
```

Ned's suggestion about putting it in a `try` block works here as well, but if you're going to go that route, one minor note: in Python 3, calling `next()` on a non-iterator raises a `TypeError`, whereas this version would raise an `AttributeError` instead.

Edit: Never mind.  As steveha points out, `operator.methodcaller()` was only introduced in 2.6, which is a shame.

Comment: I have edited R.Pate's answer to raise `AttributeError` when calling `next()` on an object that does not have a `.next()` method.

Comment: `operator.methodcaller()` looks interesting, but it was added in Python 2.6.  R.Pate's answer should work in any Python with iterators.